# Swapping states between the basis and a shape key

Tags: shape-keys

I have an object with a basis and shape key 1. How do I swap the two states so that shape key 1 becomes the new basis, while turning the basis into shape key 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate your object, on the original, remove the first shape key, the second becomes the basis. Select the copy, remove the second shape key, shift select the original object, in the dropdown menu on the right of the *Shape Keys* list, select *Join as Shapes*, it will create a brand new shape key (which was the former basis one):

[image]